# How to detect onTouch release event in Android after object is set invisible?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, human-computer-interface

## Here's what I need.

Let's say we have objects A, B. Initially object B has visibility set to `GONE` and object A has visibility set to `VISIBLE`.

Touching object A must make A `GONE` and B `VISIBLE`. Releasing B must make B `GONE` and A `VISIBLE`. Problem is that it must be done without pressing B again.

## Here's what I tried.

1. Set on touch event `ACTION_DOWN` on A and `ACTION_UP` on same A, that appears and hides B just like described. This cannot work, because `ACTION_UP` is not triggered after setting visibility of A to `GONE`.
2. Set on touch event `ACTION_DOWN` on A that will make A `GONE` and make B `VISIBLE`, at same time new event listener is set such that `ACTION_UP` on B would inverse visibility of the objects. This doesn't work either since after B appears, I need to release, press B again and then release to make it work.

## My questions.

1. Is it possible to to set onTouch listener in such way that object is assumed to be touched? So that there would be no need to press it again?
2. Is it possible to detect onTouch `ACTION_UP` event after visibility of object is set to `GONE`?

All ideas, examples, links will be appreciated.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  buttonA.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      YourMethodForButtonBGoesVisible();
      YourMethodForButtonAGoesGone();
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        YourMethodForButtonAGoesVisible();
        YourMethodForButtonBGoesGone();
    }
    return true;
 }    
});
```

I don't know if when the button A gone this will detect the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP.

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback, this is what I tried in point 1), event on object A. Unfortunately this doesn't work, `ACTION_UP` is not detected since object A is not displayed anymore.

Comment: I just found it! The reason this code didn't work was that I returned FALSE. Please edit your answer, mention to return TRUE not to block event detection and I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks too, I just wrote the code without try it, and yes the return is missing.